# Why is nylon or silk chosen to suspend pith balls in electrostatics experiments?

Tags: electrostatics, electricity, charge

In an experiment to measure the force between two charged objects two [pith balls](https://www.seattleu.edu/scieng/physics/physics-demos/electricity-and-magnetism/electrostatics---pith-balls/) are used, and they are suspended by nylon or silk threads. Why are nylon or silk chosen for the material of the threads?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE. I have tried to clarify your question. If you don't like my changes please use the edit history to undo them.

Answer (score 3):

Nylon and silk are strong, lightweight fibers which are also electrically insulating. An electrostatics experiment wouldn't work at all with a conducting metal wire. Silk probably has less moisture uptake from the air than cotton or wool, which means those fibers are probably poorer insulators even if they start out dry.

Silk thread also tends to be made from longer individual fibers than cotton or wool, and so can have less tendency to twist when under pressure — and of course nylon can be made from a single plastic extrusion, with no intrinsic twist at all.